# SceneBuilder submenus unusable

Tags: java, linux, javafx, scenebuilder

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask. If there's a better SE site for that please let me know.

Ever since I've started using SceneBuilder it's sub-menus are completely unusable, as they disappear as soon as I move the cursor to select an option.

For example - say I want to change the font size for a label. I click on the "Font" property, which opens the family, size and style properties. Now I click on the size, which opens a drop-down list of sizes, but as soon as I move the cursor to a value the drop-down list disappears! It's as if SceneBuilder thinks I've given up on selecting a value, so it should hide the drop-down again.

The exact same thing happens, for example, when trying to change properties of effects, and anywhere there is a drop-down not in the main window.

I am using the latest (8.0.0) SceneBuilder from Gluon, although the exact same thing happened on Oracle's 2.0 (which is older and not maintained, as far as I could tell).  I'm on Linux Debian 64bit, Java version 1.8.0_u40.

Any hint as to why this is happening, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally SceneBuilder does not show such a behavior. I can only imagine that this behavior is triggered by some Linux Java bug. My suggestion would be to switch to Windows or Mac (probably not an option for you :-)) or at least use a more recent version of Java in the hope that this bug has been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Hmm... yes, it appears to be a general Linux JavaFX problem: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=170047  

Reporting bugs for JavaFX is such a hassle though, and they take so long to fix, if ever, that I probably won't even bother.  And the Java version was the one bundled with SB, but using 1.8.0_u72 gives the exact same results.

Comment: Nevertheless you should do yourself and the community a favor and report the bug here: http://bugreport.java.com/

Comment: Last time I had a bug I reported it there, and it was marked to presumably be fixed in "tbd_major", which, if I understand correctly, mean it has no chance of being done for 1.8, and will probably won't be in 1.9 either. That means at least 3 years before the bug is resolved - I can't tell my clients the program will have to wait three years. By this time I would be better off learning WPF and writing the whole program in .Net from scratch.

Comment: I have filed a bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146386

Let's just hope it gets fixed in the foreseeable future.